# How do you access a variable defined by other modules user input?

Tags: python, variables, module

I am writing a program: *prog1* which is importing another module to define a variable.
It works like so:

```py
import modulename1
var1 = attribute1 #situated in modulename1
import modulename2
var2 = attribute2()
function2(var1):       # Imagine this being a api call with var1 part of url 
     #api call
     return response.text
function3(function2(var1)+ var2)
```

modulename1:

```py
attribute1 = input('user value')
```

modulename2:

```py
def attribute2():
   from prog 1 import var 1
   atr2 = function(var1) + 'word'    #Imagine the function as an api call at 
   return atr2                       #this space
```

*modulename1* accepts user `input` to define the variable *attribute1*.
now another module: *modulename2* needs to import the *var1* with the value from *modulename1*.
It can´t however import directly from *modulename1* as *prog 1* is the program launched by the User and importing *modulename1* again could result in different user `input`.
*modulename2* in Turn processes *var1* and defines *attribute2*.
*var2* is then used in *prog1* again. Is there any way to do that?

**conditions**

- Both modules have to be imported completely.
- for obvious reasons modulename2 shouldn´t import modulename1

Comment: Why are you using ``import`` to exchange dynamic data at all? While that is possible, it's much easier if, say, ``modulename2`` has a way (e.g. function) to *give* it the needed data.

Comment: how can you give data. I don´t know that yet

Comment: "for obvious reasons modulename2 shouldn´t import modulename1" Which are these? Imports are idempotent, there is no problem from importing ``modulename1`` multiple times.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OP probably has code that runs on import. We can't say for sure, since OP did not provide a [mcve], but to me this seems to be more of a XY problem paired with bad design.

Comment: @MikeScotty I don't doubt the XY and design part. I'd just like to know which assumptions we are dealing with.

Comment: yes I have code running on import namely an api call

Comment: sorry for bad design I am really new to programming